# How to read the parent item value in child item sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore

Is there any way to fetch an parent item value of the current context of an child item in sitecore.

I can access the standard value but not the actual set value of the field in the current context.

Please let me know if this can be achieved.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, from the current context, you can retrieve the parent item (and all of it's fields) as follows:

```
MultilistField parentMultilistField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Parent.Fields[...];
var parentTitle = Sitecore.Context.Item.Parent["Title"];
```

...or traverse upwards multiple levels using recursion or even Sitecore query:

```
var parentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item.Axes.Select.SelectSingleItem("./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatekey = 'sometemplate']");
```

If you are using the glass mapper, you can decorate your properties with either a [SitecoreParent] or [SitecoreQuery(...)] attribue, like so:

```
[SitecoreParent]
public virtual MyBaseItem Parent { get; set; }

[SitecoreQuery("./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatekey='sometemplate']", IsRelative = true)]
public virtual MyBaseItem RootItem { get; set; }
```